# Couldn't make a new column from the data provided within the data frame

Tags: python, if-statement, apply, seaborn

I'm trying to add the column in titanic data frame using apply function. However, I'm getting an error where the function is defined. I also tried applying .all(), .any() but I couldn't get the correct answer. What is the way to solve it?

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
titanic.head()

titanic['With(out)'] = titanic.sibsp + titanic.parch

def alone(n):
    if titanic['With(out)'] > 0:
        return 'With Family'
    else: 
        return 'Alone'

titanic['Alone'] = titanic['With(out)'].apply(alone)
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function does not ever use its argument `n`; that should ring a bell. Use

```
def alone(n):
    if n > 0:
        return 'With Family'
    else: 
        return 'Alone'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It would have never stroke in my mind.